# Testing SAML authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, saml

I'm integrating ruby-saml in a Rails 7.1 application, and I'd like to test the code using Rspec (3.12.2), but I need to figure out how to proceed.

Has anyone successfully tested SAML with Rspec?